# How do I upload an image to Firebase Storage? How do I go from a local filepath to a File object or a blob?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I have an Angular service which is supposed to have an `uploadImage()` method that takes the image's local filepath from an html form and is supposed to upload the image to a specific uri at Firebase storage (I use angular fire v7.6).

The problem is that there does not seem to be a function in Firebase (well angular/fire to be exact) that uploads the file from a local path string. Instead, there is `uploadBytes()`, which requires some other format (Blob, Bytes, I am not sure).

I have no idea nor have I been able to find how in god's name am I supposed to read the image file into that format so I can use it in `uploadBytes()`.

This is what I have so far:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Storage, ref, uploadBytes} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import {from, map, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageService {
  constructor(private firebaseStorage: Storage) { }

  uploadImage(id:number, filePath: string, name: string): Observable<string> {
    const ext = filePath.split('.').pop();
    const fileRef = ref(this.firebaseStorage, '/' + id + '/' + name + '.' + ext);
    
    const correctFormat = ??????;

    return from(uploadBytes(fileRef, correctFormat)).pipe(
      map(taskSnapshot => {
        return taskSnapshot.ref.fullPath;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you seen the file upload example in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage.md#file-upload-example)? Your File object needs to come from an HTML form. JavaScript running in a web browser can't access arbitrary files on disk, as that would be a huge security hole (what would be stopping the website from uploading the entire contents of the hard drive?) Also see [this article](https://blog.angular.io/file-uploads-come-to-angularfire-6842352b3b47).